# Clearing Twig cache only?

Tags: 8, caching

We have this large website where we would have to deploy html changes in Twig quite often. I'm looking for a solution to clear the Twig cache ONLY. So we do not have to do a general cache rebuild, which consumes a lot of CPU each time. `drush cc render` does not work, twig html still cached. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invalidate the twig cache first, like this:

```
drush php-eval "\Drupal::service('twig')->invalidate();" 
drush cc render
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but I've found that this can be as slow as running "drush cr". Also, I found that the site will break if twig templates are deleted (and that does not happen with "drush cr")